# create folders based on string in file name

Tags: batch-file

I need a batch file to create a process for a list of files in a directory.

The filename structure is, for example: `00000_AAA_132144_2012021.txt`

I need the batch to:

1 - Create  a folder name based on the numbers after the second underscore, as this is the only constant in the naming.

2 - Move the file into the new folder.

In the example of the above the batch would create a folder called `132144` and then move the file `00000_AAA_132144_2012021.txt` into the folder

For a similar requirement I used the script Endoro created for me (below). Is it possible to modify this to meet my requirement?

```
@echo off &setlocal
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d *.PDF') do (
    set "filename1=%%~i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "folder1=!filename1:~11,6!"
    mkdir "!folder1!" 2>nul
    move "!filename1!" "!folder1!"
    endlocal
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you **know** that the filenames will be the same length, you can do the following to get the numbers after the second underscore -

```
set filename=00000_AAA_132144_2012021.txt
set dirname=%filename:~10,6%
```

If the spacing may vary - you can do the following -

```
for /f "delims=_ tokens=3" %%a in ('echo %filename%') do set dirname=%%a
```

And yes, the script written for you seems to do essentially the same thing as what you're asking - I've edited it to do what you've asked -

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f %%i in ('dir /b /a-d *.txt') do (
    set "filename=%%~i"
    for /f "delims=_ tokens=3" %%a in ('echo !filename!') do set folder=%%a 
    mkdir "!folder!" 2>nul
    move "!filename!" "!folder!"
)
```

This will move all `*.txt` documents to a folder created based on the third section of the text files name. Note that this will cause problems if you have `.txt` documents in the directory that do not follow the same naming standard.

Comment: Thanks the spacing does vary so I have tried using the for 
 

 /f "delims=_ tokens=3" %%a in ('echo %filename%') do set dirname=%%a 

@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=_ tokens=3" %%a in ('echo %filename%') do set dirname=%%a 
    set "filename=%%~i"
    set "folder=!filename!"
    mkdir "!folder!" 2>nul
    move "!filename!" "!folder!"

)

but it doesn't seem to define the new folder name a files correctly

Comment: I've edited my answer. Works for me. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=c:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=c:\destdir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*_*_*_*.txt" ') DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=3delims=_" %%m IN ("%%a") DO (
  ECHO MD "%destdir%\%%m"
  ECHO MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%destdir%\%%m\"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Endoro's routine selects `.pdf` files, you've specified `.txt`

Find filenames matching the mask, find the third `_`-separated token in the name, make that directory and then move the file.

The required commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. After you've verified that the commands are correct, change `ECHO MD` to `MD` to actually create the directories and change `ECHO MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.

Append `2>nul` to suppress error messages (eg. when the directory already exists)

Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)